# "Кака-нибудь" - диалект или просторечие?

Tags: грамотная-речь, диалектизмы

Не могу понять, что это такое "кака-нибудь" - диалект или просторечие?

Answer (score 1):

Это не просторечие.

Мне не удалось установить, какие именно места родина этого диалектизма.

[Полный словарь диалектной языковой личности](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgz8zSx_bhAhW0xMQBHfj8DyAQ_AUIFCgB&cshid=1556584145987338&biw=1920&bih=969)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. [Фольклор.   Русские народные сказки.   Русские народные загадки
из сборника "Народные русские сказки" А. Н. Афанасьева](http://publicadomain.ru/russkie_narodnye_skazki/carevna-lyagushka)

> В стары годы, в старопрежни, у одного царя было три сына — все они на
>   возрасте. Царь и говорит: «Дети! Сделайте себе по самострелу и
>   стреляйте: **кака** женщина принесет стрелу, та и невеста; ежели никто не
>   принесет, тому, значит, не жениться».
>
> А у большого брата взял рубашку и сказал: «В черной избе ее носить!»
>   Разошлись царски дети; двое-то и судят между собой: «Нет, видно мы
>   напрасно смеялись над женой Ивана-царевича, она не лягуша, а
>   **кака-нибудь** хи́тра!»

Или:

[Вдруг тут поляна рядом. У этой поляны на камешках, говорит, чурпаетсе. Я думаю, рыбина **кака-нибудь**. Раньше ведь ловили, дак смекали тоже.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgz8zSx_bhAhW0xMQBHfj8DyAQ_AUIFCgB&cshid=1556584145987338&biw=1920&bih=969)

Comment: Только он отошел от магазина, как с криком «каку-каку таку яичницу» на него налетела Калерия и вцепилась в авоську. (с)

Comment: Любовь! Кака така любовь???